# How do you wait to return a value until promise is resolved?

Tags: javascript, callback, promise, asynccallback

I'm trying to write a function that doesn't return it's value until a Promise inside the function has resolved. Here's a simplified example of what I'm trying to do.

```
'use strict';

function get(db, id) {
     let p = db.command('GET', 'group:${id}');
     p.then(g => {
         g.memberNames = [];
         g.members.forEach(id => {
             User.get(db, id)
                 .then(profile => g.memberNames.push(profile.name))
                 .catch(err => reject(err));
         });
         return g;
    });
}
```

It's a function that requests a group id and returns the data for that group. Along the way it's also throwing in the user's names into the data structure to display their names instead of their user id. My issue is that this is running asynchronously and will skip over the .then callbacks. By the time it gets to return g none of the callbacks have been called and `g.memberNames` is still empty. Is there a way to make the function wait to return g until all callbacks have been called?

I've seen a lot of stuff about await. Is this necessary here? It's highly undesired to add other libraries to my project.

Comment: I think the preferred way to do this is to pass a callback to your function, which will be called when ready.

Comment: It would be better to give up on the idea of returning a value synchronously. Your database API is exposing promises, so use them as such and don't try to make it into something synchronous. You can write anything you want sticking to the asynchronous/promise pattern. It is matter of changing your point of view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your operation to return all the profile names is also async you should return a Promise fulfilled when all the other async operations complete (or reject when one of them is rejected) done with [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```
function get(db, id) {
  let p = db.command('GET', 'group:${id}');
  return p.then(g => {
    return Promise.all(g.members.map(id => {
      // NOTE: id is shadowing the outer function id parameter
      return User.get(db, id).then(profile => profile.name)
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to make the function wait to return `g` until all callbacks have been called?

Yes, there is. But you should change your way of thinking from "*wait until all the callbacks have been called*" to "*wait until all the promises are fulfilled*". And indeed, the [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) function trivially does that - it takes an array of promises and returns a new promise that resolves with an array of the results.

In your case, it would be

```
function get(db, id) {
     return db.command('GET', 'group:${id}').then(g => {
         var promises = g.members.map(id => {
//                                ^^^ never use `forEach`
             return User.get(db, id).then(profile => profile.name);
//           ^^^^^^ a promise for the name of that profile
         });
         //
         return Promise.all(promises).then(names => {
//                                    ^^^^^^^^^^ fulfills with an array of the names
             g.memberNames = names;
             return g;
         });
    });
}
```